# Potential function overloading in javascript: naming issue

Tags: javascript, overloading

I am new to Javascript but I was able to piece together something to create a random background image on page load. This was successfully used for a Div object on the page.

Since this worked well, I wanted to use this command again for a second Div object on the same page. Both Divs had separate CSS style names so I thought this would be fine. However as soon as I use both commands together, only one will work.

I assumed it was an overloading problem, but I tried renaming everything I could and it still hasn't solved it. Is there something else I need to rename that I'm missing or do I need to frame the two separate commands differently?

Below is the JS code, CSS and HTML:

Thanks in advance!

```js
/*! random background image 2*/
window.onload = function frontimage() {    
 var thediv2 = document.getElementById("topimg");
 var imgarray2 = new Array("f1.svg", "f2.svg");
 var spot2 = Math.floor(Math.random()* imgarray2.length);
 thediv2.style.background = "url(img/f-img/"+imgarray2[spot2]+")";
 thediv2.style.backgroundSize = "70%";
 thediv2.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
 thediv2.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
 thediv2.style.zIndex = "2";
 thediv2.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,204,255,0.5)";

}

/*! random background image 1*/
window.onload = function backimage() {    
 var thediv = document.getElementById("imgmain");
 var imgarray = new Array("b1.jpg", "b2.jpg", "b3.jpg", "b4.jpg", "b5.jpg");
 var spot = Math.floor(Math.random()* imgarray.length);
 thediv.style.background = "url(img/b-img/"+imgarray[spot]+")";
 thediv.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
 thediv.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
 thediv.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
 thediv.style.zIndex = "1";

}
```

```css
#bigimg {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}

#imgmain {
 background: 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 100%;
}

#topimg {
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 background-image: url(../img/f-img/f2.svg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% -25%;
 background-size:contain;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div id="bigimg">
    <section id="imgmain"></section>
 <section id="topimg"></section>    


  </div>
```

Comment: I think your second `window.onload` event handler is overriding the first one

Comment: Properties can only hold a single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), you can add as many event handlers as you want.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function frontimage() {    
  // ...
});

window.addEventListener('load', function backimage() {    
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your first window.onload by reassigning the callback function.

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
     frontimage();
     backimage();
}
```